# Adding next tableitems by button

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I want to add table item into table dynamically using button. I tried this, but nothing happened.

```
searchButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(listTable, SWT.NONE);
            item.setText("sdasda");
            searchingTools.startSearching(listTable, progressBar, searchButton, cancelButton, currentStatusLabel);

        }
    });
```

Comment: could you please provie more code?

Answer (score 0):

Fire an event from widgetSelected() that table needs to be relayout.

```
public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent e )
{
     //Add table item
     // Do your search action 
     //Fire event that table needs to be relayout - do this at the end of the method.
}
```

Then add an event handler that catches this event and relayouts the table using: table.layout();

Try it.